# Subscript out of range in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've already learn VBA, newbie, by myself. I faced with the problem: `Subscript out of range`
I cannot figure out the reason, Please help me to solve, I appreciate very much.

Here's the code:

```
Sub copy_paste()
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim x As Integer

Arr = Array("A2:I1000", "K2:M1000", "U2:U1000", "X2:Y1000", "AB2:AB1000", "AE2:AF1000", "AK2: AN1000", _
"AQ2: AQ1000", "AS2: AS1000", "BA2: BB1000", "BE2: BE1000 ")
For x = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Application.Workbooks("20140707.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Arr(i)).copy
    If Application.Workbooks("C2_development.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Value <> "" Then
    Application.Workbooks("C2_development.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlRight).Offset(0, 1). _
    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else
    Application.Workbooks("C2_development.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlRight). _
    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code is highlighted when you get the error?

Comment: Two quick things I noticed. No need to have `Next x`, `Next` is perfectly fine. Also it is `End(xlToRight)` not just `End(xlRight)`. Try either of those and let me know if you have problems still.

Comment: oh, "Subscript out of range" is here, line: Application.Workbooks("C2_development.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1). _
    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False.

Answer (score 0):

in your loop you are using `for x=`, and later you use `Arr(i)`, so my guess, change to `Arr(x)`.

You could have avoided the problem in the first place by using `Option Explicit` at the very begin of the module, wich forces you to declare each variable.

Also, `If Application.Workbooks("C2_development.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Value <> "" Then` misses a `.range("something")` beetween `Sheets("Sheet1")` and `.value`